# Did Kefka always intend to betray Emperor Gestahl?

Tags: video-games, final-fantasy

In Final Fantasy VI (III for the US) the Empire is run by Emperor Gestahl and his clownish <strike>jester</strike> general Kefka. However, on the floating continent Kefka betrays Gestahl, kills him and takes over the world for himself.

While Kefka always seemed chaotic evil to me, was this betrayal a spur of the moment affair or had Kefka planned it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kefka certainly was capable of planning ahead. His chaotic nature was no inhibition to that. He knew what he was there for. He wanted to obtain the power of the statues, the power held in balance by their placement. And he did what needed to be done to achieve that goal.

Yes, he planned to betray Gestahl from the onset.